# Installing pydotplus in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I tried installing pydotplus in canopy and received this error

```
!pip install pydotplus
Collecting pydotplus
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.',ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pydotplus/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pydotplus/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pydotplus/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pydotplus/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pydotplus/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydotplus (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pydotplus
```

Comment: Canopy version and Python version? Pip version?

Comment: Canopy version is 2.1.9.3717. Python 3.5.2. Pip 9.0.3

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: Windows. Though I think the error maybe caused due to my machine not having access to 443 port.